# where can I download complete xml file with description of file extensions

Tags: xml, file-extension

HI. I need a description of file extensions like this http://whatis.techtarget.com/file-extension-list-A/0,289933,sid9,00.html

---

It should be in xml file or in database. The structure should be like this {Type, Extension, Description}. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to put in some extra effort, the answer is:  You already have it.

Pull down the individual pages from that website, and scrape the HTML.  I glanced at the source and it looks reasonably well formatted.  At that point you can then output into XML or whatever format you need.

If you're feeling especially ambitious, you can use XSLT to directly transform the HTML on those pages into something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make it. Or contact that website and see if they'll dump it for you. People don't usually keep random resources around like that to give out when people ask.

... Although it would be nice if they did :)